# Different shapes for the 'same' parts of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I'm considering a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.empty((10,11,12))
```

Now I would expect the following shapes to be the same, but they apparently are not:

```
>>> b[0,:,1].shape
>>> (11,)
```

and

```
>>> b[0][:][1].shape
>>> (12,)
```

Can somebody explain to me why the shapes are different? I read the Numpy documentation on indexing but there it says that writing `a[k][l]` is the same as `a[k,l]`.

Comment: But that does not apply to `[:]` or expressions with `:`.

Comment: In the 2nd, `temp=b[0]` is evaluated.  Then `temp1=temp[:]`, then `temp1[1]`.  That is, separate indexing operations.  `b[0,:,1]` is one indexing operation, evaluate as a whole by `numpy`.  Trying match the two operations isn't always useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `b[0][:]` is a view of `b[0]`, so that `b[0][:][1]` is really `b[0, 1, :]`. A numeric example may help to highlight what is going on:

```
In [5]: b = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape((3, 4, 5))

In [6]: b[0]
Out[6]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [7]: b[0, :]
Out[7]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [8]: b[0, :, 1]
Out[8]: array([ 1,  6, 11, 16])

In [10]: b[0][:]
Out[10]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [11]: b[0][:][1]
Out[11]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [13]: b[0, 1, :]
Out[13]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [32]: b[0][:, 1]
Out[32]: array([ 1,  6, 11, 16])
```

Comment: I think I get it now. [:] gives a copy of the array, but using it in this way: b[0,:,1] means choose 0th position in the first dimension, slice of the complete second dimension, and choose 1st position in the third dimension, right?

Comment: Except for one common gotcha: Unlike what happens for a Python `list`, `[:]` does *not* shallow copy an `np.ndarray`; instead, it gives you a view of the original array: If you let `c = b[:]` and change any part of `c`, then the contents referred to by `b` will also change.

Comment: Then what is [:] used for at all when dealing with numpy arrays? I could just omit it and always get the same result in the examples above.

Comment: You can still use it for indexing; in the example above, `b[:] = 2` would replace all 60 numbers with a 2, and `b[:] = b[0]` would make identical the 3 outermost (4, 5)-shaped arrays in `b`.